# I am trying to put List View inside a Scroll View, but they just won't get together. I want to show a list of items and add some text at the bottom

Tags: javascript, angular, listview, nativescript, scrollview

it should look like that:

item

item

item

item

some other text

I want the list to be List View to enjoy it's benefits like virtual scrolling, but i need the whole layout to be a Scroll View so when i get to the bottom of the list i will be able to keep scrolling to the element below, but i just can't make it happened.
It is working when i give the List View Height smaller than the device screen, but when i set the Height to fill the screen i can't scroll the List and i scroll only the Scroll View.

here is my playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=P6qk9I&v=12

Answer (score 2):

ListView itself has the ability to scroll, you are not suppose to put it inside ScrollView. If you like a Label or any content below or above ListView, then use a GridLayout.

```
<GridLayout rows="*,auto">
   <ListView row="0">
      ....
   </ListView>
   <Label row="1" text="label below list"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

If you like to show the label below all list items not just always on the screen, then you should use a FooterView which is supported only in [RadListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/ng-RadListView/header-footer)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried StackLayout with scroll view?

Comment: StackLayout seems to make things simple but we get notice message that it may result in poor rendering performance.

Comment: See Manoj's answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59410579/12505744). My answer came from a place only about a month into using NS.